# Secure folder structure for php site

Tags: php

I'm a Java (SE, EE) developer and I have been working with these techs for almost 6 years, I have also worked with php for non-web apps.

Now I'm required to build a site in php but I have googled a lot and I can't find a standard folder structure for a php site. As may you know in Java EE there is a defined structure and with the web.xml you can define security in order to allow or deny access to folders in the web root.

So the question is: Is there a standard folder structure to bring security in a php site?

If there is not, how can I prevent access to folders in my site, without the need to use .htaccess nor moving my folders to a private area in the web server?

Comment: There is no standard structure. There is no standard structure for ANY website, except whatever its parent programming environment/platform and corporate policies dictate.

Comment: What kind of access are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Direct user access by url

Comment: In PHP, you normally control access to subfolders through [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) - know you want to avoid it, but that is the "answer", I guess

Comment: @Jonathan That is typically handled by your webserver. If your php is served by IIS, then you'll need to use the IIS admin to handle security, else if it is served by apache, you'll have to use either .htaccess or the global apache configs to add those restrictions. The same goes for any other webserver that you could potentially be using to serve php.

Comment: @Kevin B, you are right of course. But why should you use say ISS when using PHP? In some way the languages / http-servers are "connected" as a family. As far as I know, PHP is reduced on ISS, things like curl is not available. But perhaps I am not uptodate.

Comment: I wasn't aware curl wasn't available on iis, but i'm also not a php developer, i just use it from time to time when needed. If that is a restriction, i guess i've never had the need to use it. The fact is, php has nothing to do with the directory security.

Comment: In the case of Java webapps, your webserver IS your application server, therefore it takes care of both. With PHP, php is the application server, and apache/iis/jetty/tomcat/whatever is the webserver. The webserver controls what can and cannot be returned to the client.

Comment: That's right Kevin, I guess the "freedom" php allows, comes with the web server restrictions or lets say traits

Comment: @Kevin B, You are right, the earth is round :) was once J2EE / TomCat / JBoss developer myself. If Jonathan had not mentioned .htaccess and said "I run on ISS or XXX", I would never had comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no defined structure for PHP projects. Application frameworks invariably use well-defined structures, but that is decided individually by each framework. In addition, the developer can easily work outside these structures (the price being that "automatic" features of the framework might no longer work in some cases).

In order to prevent access to directories in your site you have to do one of the things you mentioned: either use web-server-level mechanisms such as `.htaccess` or move the directories outside the web root entirely.

That said, in many cases there is no explicit need for such security: by strictly limiting the pieces of code that can produce immediate effects (typically down to just one [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) that boots up the application) and making sure that data is contained inside PHP code (so that the web server will not reveal the contents of files) you effectively render direct access from the outside worthless.